# Troubleshooting an RS-485 communication

Tags: debian, serial-port, minicom

I have an [ND-6021 Analog Input Module](https://www.adlinktech.com/Products/Industrial_Fieldbus/RemoteI_O/ND-6021?lang=en). It is an RS-485 device that can set a variable output voltage based on the command it receives. I am trying to make it works under a Linux Debian Stretch. I have been using minicom to see if it works properly, so I issued a read configuration command: `$012<CR>`. The device answers with the message `!01320600`: `!` means it received correctly the command and the rest of the message explains how it is configured. As far as I understand, this means that the connection is set up properly and there are no hardware problems that hinder the communication.

Next step is to set the desired level of output voltage. I have connected to the device a digital voltmeter, so I can see the output voltage. I issue the command: `#0108.467<CR>` and I should read on the voltmeter a value of 8.467 volts and the device should answer with `>`, but the voltage stays at 0 and there is no answer from the device.

I have spent hours checking the syntax of the command and it is right, so I did another test. I connected the device to a Windows laptop and using termite I issued the very same commands. The reading configuration command (`$012<CR>`) works and I got the same answer as in Linux, and now also the setting voltage command works: I got the `>` answer from the device and the output voltage is set properly.

I am confused because my test shows that the communication and the hardware settings are ok, but clearly, there is something that is not working, but what?

Comment: you can try simpier alternatives to minicom `echo -en "#0108.467\r" > /dev/ttySX"` (and try with voltmetar) or `socat - /dev/ttySX,cr`, and typing command...  then playing with socat params cr/crnl/baud...

Comment: Thank you, both commands worked like a charm. And they also can run over a ssh connection, minicom has problem with that. That leaves me puzzled, as I thought that minicom was the best software for serial communication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

usally it is a baudrate or new-line-interpretation problem. (even if commands partially works)

[socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html) is the great tool for making and troubleshooting network and serial connections.

```
socat - /dev/ttySX[,params]
```

if empty params do not working, you can try adding explicit baud rate with param:  b9600/b19200/b57600/b115200 ... all list retrieved with `socat -?? | grep 'b[1-9]'`

then focusing on new-line-interpretation problem, trying combinations of params: `cr`, `crnl`, `echo=0` and `raw`

... because some modules insist on cr+lf (\r\n) line ending, some wants just '\n', sometimes back-echoing creates confusion ... and in your case module need carriage return (\r) only, so `echo '#0108.467' | socat - /dev/ttySX,cr` should work well.